# Remove AUTH user from right sidebar in DJANGO JAZZMIN admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1khl.jpg)

Hello there!

I want to remove Auth user from left side bar as show in picture above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I made this with css only:

1. Create a file: **your-static-folder/css/custom-theme.css**
2. Put this style:

```
.user-panel {
    display: none !important;
}
```

2. In your settings.py, add:

```
JAZZMIN_SETTINGS = {
    ...
    "custom_css": 'css/custom-theme.css',
    ...
}
```